# Opening a URL stored in a JavaScript Variable

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var user_url = document.getElementById('pdurl').value;  
    if ( document.getElementById("menu").value == 'en' ) {
        window.open(user_url);

    } 
}
```

Comment: `function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}`

Comment: What was your error, what is your goal, can you please provide a little bit more information, explanation. What have you tested, tried to find a solution.

Comment: Is that a question or some kind of documentation?

Comment: Thank for your time and effort in replying, really appreciate it. I am trying to create a form for my client where a user submits a URL and selects a value from the dropdown list. I wrote a code where it checks for the value selected from the dropdown and opens the amended version of the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Window open function needs second parameter. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open. This second parameter is the name of new window. It is also a good habit to make a new variable, for the new window, so You can change something in the future.

Updated code of line:

```
var newwindow = window.open(user_url, 'windowname');
```

---

I just realize, that `target= "_blank"` or window name set to `"blank"` is not so obvious (mentioned in the comments). Read that: [window.open with target "_blank" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035937/window-open-with-target-blank-in-chrome). As You can see: **"_blank is not guaranteed to be a new tab or window. It's implemented differently per-browser"**. In that case, it is safer to use just a new name of the window, or use _tab instead. Updated my answer so the target is now just a `'windowname'`.

---

**Update:** in comments, you asked how to pass parameters to this new window url. If you mean `get` parameters (that can be used in server side script later, for example php) use simple string concatenation:

```
user_url = user_url + '?parameter=value';
var newwindow = window.open(user_url, 'windowname');
```

Comment: that is what I commented

Comment: @BhargavModi then why not write it as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @WimOmbelets I had written but it had gone into comment I dont know why any ways answer is important not the timing

Comment: Answers going in as comment ??.. Is that a BUG or any AI implementation in SO that automatically decides where it should go?

Comment: Thank you so much... it worked. However, I had a another doubt. How can  I add parameters to the url stored in the variable?

Comment: I want to add extra parameters to the existing URL. For ex: If the user submits www.google.com, I want to be able to add /trends at the end. Please ignore the language, I am new to programming.

Comment: Then replace ' ?parameter=value' with: ' /trends'