# Is it true that attempting to open a url in a new window will only open another tab?

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Been looking around for an answer to this.  Thought I had found a solution but it didn't work.  Here's what I tried.

1. Created a javascript function as follows:

   function openInNewWindow( url ){

   window.open( url, '_blank', 'height=200' );}
2. Created a hotspot with the following in the computed value:

   @URLOpen("javascript:openInNewWndow('http://www.google.com')")

This just replaces the current tab but does not open a new browser window.  Is there another way to do this?

thanks
clem

Comment: This might be due to a browser setting. What browser(s) are you testing in?

Comment: Tried it in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera.  All have the same behavior.

Comment: I might have made a coding error.  Forget this for now until I make sure I'm implementing this correctly.

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035937/window-open-with-target-blank-in-chrome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696041/window-openurl-blank-not-working-on-imac-safari

Comment: Have you tried a @SetTargetFrame("_blank"); before teh @UrlOpen() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @openurl just didn't work.  I finally got it to work using this on the form:

```
[<a href="#" onclick="openInNewWindow('http://google.com')">Test</a>]
```

Thanks for the replies.  Appreciate the input.

clem

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `fullscreen` option.

```
window.open("http://example.com","_blank","fullscreen=0");
```

But your program can't do anything with popup blockers.

Answer (score 0):

```
@URLOpen("javascript:openInNewWndow('http://www.google.com')")
```

Is that your actual code pasted in? because you missed the '**i**' in openInNewW**i**ndow

Also, I'm not sure you can specify a height without specifying a width.

You might also investigate how @urlopen works, there shouldn't be any need to mix in javascript at all.

> When a Notes browser triggers the @URLOpen function, it displays the retrieved Web page in a new window. When the @URLOpen function is used on a form or page that is accessed by a non-Notes browser, Domino generates a javascript window.open command with the following syntax:

```
window.open( [sURL] [, sName] [, sFeatures] [, bReplace])
```

> To display the retrieved Web page in a new window, pass the values for sName and sFeatures (if desired) as comma-separated arguments within the urlstring. For example,

`@URLOpen("http://www.ibm.com','NEW")`

> Be sure to use double quotes at the beginning and end of the urlstring parameter, and single quotes before and after each comma separating the arguments to be passed to window.open. Do not include any spaces.

[IBM Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_URLOPEN.html)