# Jquery open href if src=

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use Jquery to search a table of images for any that match the defined parameters within the src, and if found to then open the href in a new window. The href comes before the img src in the website code, which I believe I've compensated for in my Jquery.

Unfortunately I'm unsure why the Jquery is not working - could anybody take a look at it and give me a nudge in the right direction? I suspect the problem is in opening the specified href, but for the life of me I can't spot the problem. Thanks in advance.

```js
$('img[src$=random.gif]').each(function() {
      $img = $(this);
      $link = $url.closest('a');
      var href = $link.attr('href');
        var win = window.open.attr('href', '_blank');
        win.focus();
      });
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = window.location.href }, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td>
<a href="/link">
<img src="/random.gif">
</a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$img` is the `$(this)` **image** than instead of `$url.closest('a');` you should point to `$img`

```
  $img = $(this);
  $link = $img.closest('a');
```

Edited example: **https://jsfiddle.net/4ua4p5pf/**

```
$('img[src$="random.gif"]').each(function() {

    var $img = $(this);
    var href = $img.closest('a').attr('href');

    setTimeout(function () {
       var win = window.open( href, "Image description", "status,resizable,scrollbars");
       // var win = window.open( href, "image"); // open in new tab
       win.focus();
    }, 500);

});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
[window.open with target "_blank" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035937/window-open-with-target-blank-in-chrome)