# How to call a APEX page in separate window, while calling it from EBS

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-ebs

I have successfully extended  EBS  to launch APEX page. Now, When I click on the APEX responsibility-menu-function in EBS, the EBS page gets replaced by the APEX page. But I want to open the APEX page in a new window. So that my EBS page still stays.

Can you please suggest a way how we can do that. Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change the link that launches your Apex page so the link (aka "a" includes the attribute:

```
target="_blank"
```

Comment: Hi..Can you please specify where exactly I need to add this attribute..My APEX Page is launched from form Function from EBS, where I am providing : GWY.jsp?targetAppType=APEX&p=200:3:::::EBS_RESP_ID, EBS_APP_ID,EBS_SEC_GROUP:[RESPONSIBILITY_ID],[RESP_APPL_ID],[SECURITY_GROUP_ID] as value. Do I need to specify the attribute here or at some other place ? And how can I do that ?

Comment: It's a standard attribute of the <a href="..."> HTML tag. I don't do EBS, just Apex, so I can't help with that part. Good luck.

Comment: If you liked my answer, would you mind marking it "Correct"? I could use the points. Thanks.

Comment: It is not completely the right answer, as it just opens the blank page in new window. all the page content is lost.

Comment: Did you include the rest of the URL with your page?  e.g. your_domain.com/f?p=&APP_ID.:&NEW_PAGE_ID.:&SESSION.:::::

Comment: Yes I Did...  I called it like this in the EBS function : javascript:window.open(“GWY.jsp?targetAppType=APEX&p=200:1:::::EBS_RESP_ID, EBS_APP_ID,EBS_SEC_GROUP:[RESPONSIBILITY_ID],[RESP_APPL_ID],[SECURITY_GROUP_ID]“,  “_blank”)

Comment: Check this out. I'm thinking it's the right answer for your need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11036018/1529154